# How can I create a div which doesn't resize itself when the inner content changes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a media feed, which may contain text, images, videos, etc. Some of these posts may be explicit, so I want to hide the content of the post with a warning, which the user would have to click to see the post.

I've successfully done this, except the div containing he post changes size when the warning is clicked. How can I change this so that the size of the div remains constant when the inner content changes?

Comment: Can  i see your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code which does not resize div. It will allow to scroll content within fixed size.

eg.

```
<div class="text-center" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
//contents inside div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `div` style to:

```
height: 100px; // or max-height with any other value
overflow: scroll; // for scrolling content if it's height greater than div's height
```

Comment: The max height is not known

Comment: Provide JSFiddle to understand what you want